# How to access list of Jenkins job parameters from within a JobDSL script?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I would like to save the parameters passed into a JobDSL job. I know I can refer to individual parameters but I would like to make the code generic. How would I access the list of parameters passed to the job?

The current code looks something like:

```
final jobParameters = new File('parameters')
jobParameters.write("""
    |AOEU=${AOEU}
    |SNTH=${SNTH}
"""[1..-1].stripMargin().trim())
```

I would like to be able to get it to look something like:

```
final jobParameters = new File('parameters')
jobParameters.write(params.iterator().join('\n'))
```

`params` is something that's available in the Build Flow Plugin but not the JobDSL Plugin.

Comment: Any code snippet as starting point?

Comment: I've added sample code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The DSL does not offer access to the build parameters. But the script has access to the Jenkins object model, so you can use the Jenkins API to retrieve the current build and its parameters:

```
import hudson.model.*

Build build = Executor.currentExecutor().currentExecutable
ParametersAction parametersAction = build.getAction(ParametersAction)
parametersAction.parameters.each { ParameterValue v ->
    println v
}
```

Answer (score 9):

This is how I do it for debugging (I read it somewhere, I'm by no means a Groovy or Job DSL expert...):

```
binding.variables.each {
  println "${it.key} = ${it.value}"
}
```

This shows all the existing environment variables, including the job parameters.

```
JOB_NAME = job-generator
...
NEXT_PROJECTS = baz,bat
...
PROJECT_TYPE = Software
...
PROJECTS = foo,bar
...
SHELL = /bin/bash
```

Comment: this works like a dream! nice and simple, exactly what i needed!